# I don't get why my equality operator implementation dosen't work here and returns true

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class SomeObject {
    final List list;
    final int integer;
    SomeObject({required this.integer, required this.list});
    @override
    bool operator == (Object other) {
        if (other is SomeObject && integer == other.integer) {
            if (other.list.length != list.length) {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                if (list[i] == other.list[i]) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false; 
    }
     
    @override
    // TODO: implement hashCode
    int get hashCode => Object.hashAll(list);
}


void main(){
    var b = SomeObject(integer: 4, list: [5, 6, 7]);
    var c = SomeObject(integer: 4, list: [5, 6, 8]);
    print(b == c);
    // Here equality operator returns true while it should return false. 
    // I think there is some problem in comparing individual list elements.
}
```

Comment: Your loop stops at the first element being equal in the lists. You should instead check for if they are not equal and return false. If the loop completes, all elements must be equal and you can then return true.

Comment: So you mean if it returned false it wont stop at first element?

Comment: "list[i] == other.list[i]" should be "list[i] != other.list[i]" and you should then return false in the loop and return true after the loop.

Comment: The reason is you want to check all the elements and check if they are all equal and not just stop after the first equal elements. But if we find one example where they are not equal, we can just stop the loop by returning false since it does not matter if the rest of the elements are equal or not

Comment: thanks got it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `!=` and return `false` in this part:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  if (list[i] == other.list[i]) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

If we look carefully why it is failing:

```
var b = SomeObject(integer: 4, list: [5, 6, 7]);
var c = SomeObject(integer: 4, list: [5, 6, 8]);
```

First loop: i = 0

```
if (list[0] == other.list[0]) { // 5 == 5
  return true; // it stops and immediately returns true 
}
```

If we use `!=` and return `false`, it will break the loop as soon as the elements at index `i` are not equal.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  if (list[i] != other.list[i]) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Last loop: i = 2

```
if (list[2] != other.list[2]) { // 7 == 8 
  return false; 
}
```

But if you want a shorter way to do this:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class SomeObject {
  final List list;
  final int integer;

  SomeObject({
    required this.list,
    required this.integer,
  });


  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    return other is SomeObject &&
        listEquals(other.list, list) &&
        other.integer == integer;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => list.hashCode ^ integer.hashCode;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,well explained:),btw that XOR operation at int get hashcode is done just to get a unique sequence of digits,right?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes. You can check how it works here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#bitwise-and-shift-operators